# How to determinate round by element in tree (Tournament brackets)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, algebra, tournament

Assume we have following tree:

```
1
    9
2
        13
3
    10
4 
            15
5
    11
6 
        14
7   
    12
8
```

Where elements(matches):
1-8 is round 1
9-12 is round 2
13-14 is round 3
15 is round 4

**How I can determinate round of element "n" in shuch tree?**

My current formulas are:

```
total_rounds = floor(log(totalTeams,2));

matches_per_round = (totalTeams / pow(2, current_round))

next_match_id = (totalTeams/2) + ceil(match_id/2)

total_matches = total_teams - 1
```

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imagine the tree was numbered in reverse.

```
15
     7
14
         3
13 
     6
12 
             1
11
     5 
10 
         2
9   
     4
8
```

In that case, it'd simply be the logarithm of the number, rounded down. Now we simply subtract this number from the number of rounds, and we're done.

```
reverse_number = total_matches - match_number + 1;
reverse_match_round = floor(log(reverse_number, 2));
match_round = total_rounds - match_round;
```

(Note, `reverse_match_round` is actually 0-indexed, unlike match_round. However, since we subtract it from `total_rounds`, it's easier to keep it that way than to 1-index it. If you prefer it 1-indexed, simply add `+1` to each of the last two lines.)